# Stopping while bash

Tags: bash

I use this bash.sh to start and restart on failure my game server. It is run @reboot

```
while true; do
./Server
done
```

Periodically i need to update that server, while it is off. Turning it off seems impossible. In other scripts and languages i use an

```
if ($exists(filename.txt)) { halt }
```

in the while loop of an otherwise unbreakable process which allows me to place a single empty file into the process directory that if present halts the script from restarting the process once killed. This seems like the easiest solution for me. How can I do this in this case?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you have an infinite loop executing the `Server` file/script/binary?

Comment: @Fl.pf. The Bash.sh was given to me by the Server's developer as a means to restart the server on critical failure. It did seem to me at the time that it would constantly be trying to do as you say. But I see no multiple instances or signs of processes over usage. Should i be concerned?

Comment: never trust developers to do sysadmin stuff.  especially if they think that restarting a service in an endless loop is a good, or even acceptable, way to deal with critical failures.  that's not even good development practice (there's a bug, it ought to be fixed not hidden or ignored), let alone good sysadmin practice.

Comment: @cas So what I'm hearing is that this bash is not the best idea. Let's put my expectations save one aside: what I have is a Game ./Server It must restart on critical failure.

1) What might be the best way to restart it always?
2) What is a way to prevent this always-restart if needed for servicing?

Answer (score 6):

That would be:

```
until [ -e filename.txt ]; do
  ./Server
done
```

Same as:

```
while [ ! -e filename.txt ]; do
  ./Server
done
```

If on Linux, you could also do:

```
while true; do
  # wait for filename.txt to be removed if it's there:
  inotifywait -qe DELETE_SELF filename.txt 2> /dev/null
  ./Server
done
```

To only prevent `Server` from being started while the file is there, but start again as soon as it's removed.

If you're administrator on the machine, it would make more sense to add that as a service handled by your init system that would take care of properly daemonizing it, restarting (respawn) upon unexpected exit if required, etc. Then, you'd do `service whatever stop` before editing, and `start` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `break` command like this:

```
while true; do
    ./Server
    if [ -e filename.txt ] ; then
        break
    fi
done
```

But the above script will run all the time `./Server` which can be dangerous

Comment: `test -e "$file"` or `[ -e "$file" ]` to [test](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) if a file exists in the shell